# Javascript (prototype) plugin to cycle through images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Can anyone recommend a javascript plugin that rotates some small images on a card.

For an example of the functionality I want check out http://sortfolio.com

Would prefer Prototype implementation, but JQuery could work also if necessary.

I'm curious to see if there are any other cool implementations of this too (such as just hovering the mouse over the image and moving it left or right).

More generally - where is the best place to find and rate plugins like this?  I'm surprised that I couldn't find a big site that listed and rated them all.  Maybe github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading their javascript file it looks like they are using a modified version of this:

http://github.com/simplabs/glider

Search for "glider" in
http://asset0.sortfolio.com/sprockets.js

Answer (score 0):

Just google jQuery image carousel

[There are some good ones here](http://blarnee.com/wp/jquery-image-carousels-for-slidehow/)

Also check out [jQuery.com](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/image+carousel)